# variable #include // including files based on a variable

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, include

I want to do something which would achieve something like this:

```
 std::string filename;
 #include filename;
```

Is there anyway this is possible? (C++)

To clarify:
I don't necessarily mean using #include, but something that would achieve that result.
Basically I want to write a series of C++ scripts, if you were, save them in text files, and paste one of them into a function, with their filename variable. So like:

```
void bar()
{
    std::cout << "I'm a function";
}

class foo;
{
     void activate(std::string filename)
        {
            /* paste file filename here, where file could be something like:

               'std::cout << "hello world";
                bar();'                     

                or whatever, calling different functions in different orders
                and generally doing completely different things.
            */  
         }
}; 

foo myobj;
int main()
{
      myobj.activate("file1.txt");
      myobj.activate("file2.txt");
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor is unrelated to the C++ language (other than being specified in the same standard), so... nope.

Comment: No, that's not possible! The `#include ` statement is resolved before the compiler sees `filename` at all.

Comment: This would not make any sense.  `filename` is created and initialized at runtime.  The preprocessor directives are run prior to compilation.

Comment: No but you can do `#if` etc with preprocessor commands.  Was making a detailed answer when the question got closed.  :-/

Comment: Sort of. You can do `#include WHATEVER` or `#include FOO(BAR, BAZ)`, where `WHATEVER` and `FOO` are macros which evaluate to a suitable token sequence (a path delimited by quotes of angle brackets).

Comment: How do I unhold this question now I've edited it? And Angew, I have no idea what you just said. Example?

Comment: It sounds like you want to embed a scripting engine into your program.  Lua has a reputation for being easy to embed and expose functions and objects from C++ to the script.

Comment: @Chrysm_Seal Reopen: you don't, other vote on it (I just did, the question seems clear enough to me now). As for the macros, see this [example](http://ideone.com/Tcmp1l)

Comment: Ok thanks guys. So basically no. lol.

Comment: Would the end result of what you want be done at runtime (i.e. like something you can do with other scripting languages like PHP or shell scripts) or is this sort of way to save you from having to type a bunch of the same files/code (i.e. have a bunch of files that have exactly the same code but only 1+ function is different)?

Comment: The first option, I think. It's not to save time or anything, I basically have an Activate function for each NPC(which is called when you interact with them), and want different NPCs to do different things, say one to CreateMessageBox() and another to ChangeGameMode("Battle", "Enemy_1") etc

Comment: Decided to go with my original idea, which was to make a polymorphic GameEvent class, which contains a list/vector of object type Events, with derived classes such as event_start_battle etc, with an inherited virtual void Execute, defined differently for each of those derived classes where I can call what I want, with each individual event being objects of said classes, with a global event_maker function which i call before the main game loop (with all of my other _maker functions such as object_maker, enemy_maker) where I can define the parameters etc.